# Activate HTML button (onClick function) from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

How do I activate existing HTML button, say running the onClick function in specific button?

When using document.getElementById("Button ID").onclick I get the function with the parameters, like the following example. but how do I run the function?

**Example**, the document.getElementById("Button ID") result is:

ƒ onclick(event) {calculate('ABC',1,8)}

In this example, how do I run **calculate('ABC',1,8)** function from javascript?

Comment: Couldn't you do document.getElementById("Button ID").onclick(); ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `click` method on the button element.

```
document.getElementById("Button ID").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply call the [click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) function on the same element.

```
document.getElementById("Button ID").click()
```

This will trigger the `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 1):

- A function is called using parenthesis `()`, i.e: `fn()`.
- What you're getting is the declaration of that function.

**You need to call it as follow:**

```
document.getElementById("Button ID").click();
```

I recommend you to read about `addEventListener` and Event `click`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const calculate = (p1, p2, p3) => {
    return p2 + p3
}

document.getElementById("Button ID").onclick = () => {
    const res = calculate('ABC',1,8)
    alert (res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks to take time to answer the question. Though this can be an answer, is better if you format the code and explain what you do.